# Why `scipy.dot is numpy.dot` False?

Tags: numpy, scipy, dot-product

Why is that false? well, the dot product is same in whole math.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Up until scipy 1.4.0, `scipy.dot` was exactly the same as `numpy.dot`, and `scipy.dot is numpy.dot` would return True.  As of scipy 1.4.0, `scipy.dot` is deprecated, as are all the other numpy names that had been copied to the `scipy` namespace.  You can read about it in the [SciPy 1.4.0 release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.4.0.html#scipy-deprecations).  The wrapper function for `scipy.dot` that generates the deprecation warning is no longer exactly the same function object as `numpy.dot`, so `scipy.dot is numpy.dot` returns False in scipy 1.4.0 and later versions.

Comment: But still that can't be false, that's a universal truth.

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics.  This is a question about objects defined in a computer program.

Comment: If it is abt computer program then why did it not said tht scipy.dot does not exist or something like that.